# How to open IOS Maps on Flutter Framework

Tags: dart, flutter, maps

I can open Google Maps with flutter framework. What do I need to do to open Apple maps?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Do you want to open the IOS maps app, in a browser, in a view inside your application?

Comment: @Muzaffer did my solution work? If no do let me know where you got stuck.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad i've tried this method while running google maps i'll make a comeback after trying for ios map

Comment: @Niklas I want to open Ios map app, Try opening google maps as cops says. i couldn't find a document about ios map

Comment: its worked. How do I get the address and directions by car? I did this for Google Maps. https://www.google.com/maps/dir/${appCommon.separator}api=1&origin=&destination=${appCommon.mapAdress}&travelmode=driving

Comment: @Muzaffer I don't claim to be an expert on this, please see apple docs for all the urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String url = 'https://maps.apple.com/?q=0,0'; // I used 0,0 as latitude and longitude
if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  launch(url);
} else {
  // error in launching map
}
```

You need [this plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher)

Answer (score 0):

Use [apple_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/apple_maps_flutter) which is a flutter plugin that provides an Apple Maps widget. To open apple map only in ios device, you can make a platform check.

Comment: How do you open on maps using `apple_maps_flutter`?